# Winterbash 2020 is live!

Tags: discussion

[Time to get those hats](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/).

[Network leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network)

[Travel leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com)

[Unofficial list of hats on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357915/winter-bash-2020-hat-list)

Answer (score 3):

[Network leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network)

Currently:

- U11-Forward - 25
- Mark Mayo
- Panda - 23
- Peter Haddad - 23

Comment: Should this be updated? I updated the other answer that's a Community Wiki. Anyway, happy new year :)

Comment: I do not feel the need to update it. The only one would would be in the top 5 has not answered this question. But if anyone like to, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

[Travel Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com)

Currently:

- Willeke - 25
- Mark Mayo - 19
- Xnero - 17
- JonathanReez - 15
- mlc - 14
- Zach Lipton - 13

Comment: I'm actually fifth!! ;) Clicking on the blue cap on my Activity page I can see the networks where I earned each cap, but is there a page where I can see how many hats I earned on each network? This would be a proper Meta SE question maybe

Comment: If you follow the link in the other answer you can find your place in the overall list, it is at the top of the list, above the actual list. I have never seen a 'split out per site' number, I usually go to the leaderboard list per site, follow it to the site I expect to do well and click on that list.

Comment: This is the sites leaderboard: https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard and if you are in the top 5 your avatar is in the line of avatars.